# Angular not send array?

Tags: angular

How can i send a array with EventEmmitter?

**************** init component 1*************

```
@Output()
    notifyMeets: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter();
```

i want send the data: data is array, how can i send array?

**file listUserComponent.js**

```
this.listMeetService.getMeets(this.user.id).pipe(
            mergeMap(data => {
                const observablesList = [];
                this.notifyMeets.emit(data);
                return forkJoin(observablesList);
            })
        ).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.friends = response[0];
            this.discriminar();
        });
```

i try get value of array

**************** init component 2*************

```
<ion-card-header (notifyMeets)='getNotificationMeet($event)'> Tus Grupos  </ion-card-header>
```

but never is show the console, why? what is the problem?

**file listMeetComponent.js**

```
getNotificationMeet(evt) {
        console.log('OSOAAAA', evt);
        this.listMeets = evt;
    }
```

the two components is in the **same level**

**i should use @input?**

```
<span>
//first component
    <app-list-user >
    </app-list-user>
//second component    
    <app-list-meet>
    </app-list-meet>
</span>
```

Comment: Hope you `subscribe` (or use `async` in the template to trigger subscribe) the observable which has `mergeMap(data => .......)`? Can you please check?

Comment: When you say same level? What do you mean by it? Means both are in the same template? Is your getMeets() subscription and getNotificationMeet() method are in same file? As per Angular output should be used to notify parent component from the child component. Can you please share your template/html code?

Comment: @user2216584 getMeets() and getNotificationMeet() are in different files, are two componentes

Answer (score 0):

`@Input` and `@output` are used when the components have parent child relationship. Since you have component on same level , you need to use `observables` to handle this.

Example:

Create a eventService/messagingService:

**msgSvc.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
   private someEvent$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

   constructor(){}

   emitSomeEvent(someArr: any[]){
      this.someEvent$.next(someArr);
   }

   someEventListner(){
      return this.someEvent$.asObservable();
   }

}
```

Now in component file,

**listUserComponent.js**

```
constructor(private msgSvc: MessagingService ){
 // and other service injection....
}
this.listMeetService.getMeets(this.user.id).pipe(
            mergeMap(data => {
                const observablesList = [];
                this.msgSvc.emitSomeEvent(data);
                return forkJoin(observablesList);
            })
        ).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.friends = response[0];
            this.discriminar();
        });
```

in **listMeetComponent.js**

```
msgSubscription : Subscription;
constructor(private msgSvc: MessagingService ){
 // and other service injection....
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.msgSubscription = this.msgSvc.someEventListner().subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
  })
}

ngOnDestroy(){
   // make sure to unsubscribe when component is destroyed to avoid bugs
   this.msgSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: the second component is create and 
after some time passes the next() function is executed, how to solved

Comment: @yaha : update your question with some code of this scenario. I am not able understand your point

Comment: i want to talk with you by chat please